# Proxmox hook for VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, hook, proxmox

We have Proxmox installation. We want to execute a command after new VM was added. It is required for QEMU port redirection since setting redir option is not avaialble on GUI: qm set 102 -args "--redir tcp:30102::3389"

Is there a way to hook to proxmox vm post-create event and execute a binary with vm id as an attribute?

As an alternative approach I was thinking about watching fs file create events under /etc/pve/qemu-server/ path, but I don't think it's a right way for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same kind of problem. I wanted to change an IP failover redirection as soon as the virtual machine is migrated to another node but I could not find a clean way to detect the said migration.

The log files `/var/log/pve/tasks/index` does not help. Only the node that is giving the VM is having a line of log that says "qmigrate" or "hamigrate".

I've found a way to watch the `/etc/pve/qemu-server` files with `inotifywait` and then read the VM informations in that file and it's working. Also, you should exclude the *tmp* files detection, those are not relevant. Maybe there is a better way to do it, but that method works 100% of the time for me even when a node is down.